# How express the expression /\s(([a-z][a-z]|[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z])[a-z]?)([0-9]{1,4}[a-z]?)/gi inJava

Tags: javascript, java

I am mainly working on grab information from text file and tries to get flight numbers. I found an example of  `/\s(([a-z][a-z]|[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z])[a-z]?)([0-9]{1,4}[a-z]?)/gi` in javascript. How can I translate it into java? especially for the `/gi` part.

Comment: see `Pattern` javadoc (look for "flags"), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: I tried but did not find a matched one.

Comment: Then post the code that's not working

Comment: The post code was from javascript not java. I am trying to convert it into java.

Comment: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s(([a-z][a-z]|[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z])[a-z]?)([0-9]{1,4}[a-z]?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); Matcher m = p.matches("your-input-string"); while (m.find()) { // do something with m.group(nnn) }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
and for the g modifier, I can try find the match in a while loop to achieve this.